# How can I correct Spring Boot unit test failed to load application context in one of two nearly identical test classes?

Tags: java, spring-boot-test

I am building unit tests for a Spring Boot application that will call a couple of web services. One service builds a PDF and the other stores that document, and there are separate classes to call these services. I'm using IntelliJ for an IDE.

When I have a single test class to run all of my tests, things start up and work fine. When I have two separate test classes, the first class continues to work fine but when running the second I receive

```
ERROR [main] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication: Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name...
Could not resolve placeholder 'PDF.form.serviceURL' in value "${PDF.form.serviceURL}"
```

The classes are annotated with the following, for the application context to start

```
 @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
 @SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
```

What would cause one test class to run without issue, and an identical test class to fail to start the application context?

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, the problem was related to the JUnit configuration in IntelliJ. Without the appropriate environment options, the context would not start correctly, causing the error.